# Search for Tags with Super Search

Tags: solspace, supersearch, tags

Is it possible to use Super Search keyword parameter to search for Tags?  I have Super Search and Tags, and I'm trying to include a way to search for tags.

So if I had a tag called "space" and I search for Outer Space in the keyword field, I could get "space" as a Tag result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search for Solspace Tags in the `keywords` field. From the documentation (https://solspace.com/docs/super_search/search/#keywords):

> The keywords field allows your users to perform a search on across all entries on your site. By default, keyword searches look into all searchable custom fields and titles. Please make sure that each custom field is marked as searchable in the custom fields' settings in the EE CP. Search terms are inclusive (so all words searched on must be present in the entry to show up as a valid result), search on words within words (a search for cat could return caterpillar), **and also search into Solspace Tag add-on tags (if installed)**.

Comment: Which loop do you use to print the tag name the search finds?  The docs show how to show entries tags are in, or tags that are a part of that entry, but I'm not quite understanding how to display matching tags themselves.

Comment: Actually, I think the answer might lead to some confusion: **Super Search's results are always Channel Entries**, not Solspace Tag tag themselves. If your search term is a tag (eg. "outdoors"), Super Search will display **channel entries** that have the tag (eg. "outdoors") associated with them. Then, if you want to display the tags associated with each entry, you could use Tag's `{exp:tag:tags}` tag pair and pass the `{entry_id}`. Again, Super Search doesn't search for the tags themselves.

Comment: That's what I thought.  The docs are worded in a way that makes it seem like you can search tags.  So is there a way to search for tags at all?  Like, in the module view for Tag there's a search box, works well.  Is there something like that to search using back-end or most people solve it with like a JS sort?

Comment: In the docs, I think the difference in meaning between "searching tags" and "searching _on_ tags" may not be clear enough. It's noted. Unfortunately Super Search doesn't search Solspace Tag tags, nor does the Tag module have a search feature for searching its tags. I suggest making a feature request here: http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions